# "This movie format is not supported" - Strange issue with UIImagePickerController on iPad (iOS v 4.3)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

My basic requirement is to capture video using UIImagePickerController. The recording of video should automatically stop after recording 10 seconds of video.

I am getting pretty weird error on iPad 2 (iOS ver 4.3) - "This movie format is not supported" when the video reaches its maximum duration on iPad2.

Here is my piece of code. The code works absolutely fine on iPhone, but gives - "This movie format is not supported" when the video reaches its maximum duration on iPad2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
(void) launchCamera : (BOOL) bAlbum         
    {   
    UIImagePickerController * pImgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
    pImgPicker.delegate = self;

    pImgPicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:pImgPicker.sourceType];
    if(m_bRecordVideo)
    {
        pImgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [pImgPicker setVideoQuality: UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium];
        [pImgPicker setCameraCaptureMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];
        [pImgPicker setVideoMaximumDuration:10];
    }
    else
    {
        pImgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [pImgPicker setCameraCaptureMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:pImgPicker animated:YES];
    [pImgPicker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to above problem.

The following line fixed the issue.

pImgPicker.mediaTypes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString*) kUTTypeMovie, nil] autorelease];

Here is the updated code.

```
-(void) launchCamera : (BOOL) bAlbum
{
    UIImagePickerController * pImgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pImgPicker.delegate = self;

    pImgPicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:pImgPicker.sourceType];
    if(m_bRecordVideo) 
    {
        pImgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        pImgPicker.mediaTypes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString*) kUTTypeMovie, nil] autorelease];

        [pImgPicker setVideoQuality: UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium];
        [pImgPicker setCameraCaptureMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];
        [pImgPicker setVideoMaximumDuration:10];
    }
    else
    {
        pImgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [pImgPicker setCameraCaptureMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:pImgPicker animated:YES];
    [pImgPicker release];
}
```

Thanks,
--Prem